# C# stream from DataTable to MailMessage attachment

Tags: c#, .net, excel, csv, mailmessage

New to software development, just wondering could you stream data from a DataTable to a ZipFile object? Heres how I imagine this going down:

1. I have a C# method which takes a sql query parameter, goes off to a database and returns data in the form of a DataTable.
2. Ideally an Excel or CSV physical file would not need to be created. Surely a stream could be set up to create an Excel or CSV object
3. This would need to be converted to a zip file
4. The zip file would be added to a MailMessage attachment

To summarize, I have data in a sql database. A C# application allows a user to create a report of their own design and it is now required that this report be sent out via email subscription. Due to size of data, a zipped attachment is necessary to send the mail as opposed to putting it in the body of the mail.

Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way. Any suggestions appreciated. I understand there is a lot in there so any pointers or advice is welcome.
Thanks!

Comment: Simple.  Foreach the rows of the `DataTable` -> Write to text stream -> With a stream onhand, you can add to mailmessage like this: `MailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, ContentType))`.  One gotcha! is that you should set the `stream.Position = 0` when you're done, BEFORE you make the `new Attachment` object.

Comment: You can write datatable to an Xml and the send xml.  Then can be read at receiving end.  Xml can be dropped into a spread sheet and viewed easily.

Comment: Thanks @Kyle, really helpful!